# FireMonkey: How to draw a focus rectangle on a bitmap?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm porting  to XE5/FireMonkey a VCL application which makes use of Canvas.DrawFocusRect. This doesn't exists in FireMonkey so the question is: How do I replace DrawFocusRect?

If this matters, the canvas is a TPaintBox canvas.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Would a TSelection be suitable: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Objects.TSelection

It's a component which draws a draggable/resizeable rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can draw the focus rect the first time.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRectF;
begin
  R := PaintBox1.AbsoluteRect;
  InflateRect(R, -0.5, -0.5);
  PaintBox1.Canvas.BeginScene;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.DrawDashRect(R, 0, 0, AllCorners, PaintBox1.AbsoluteOpacity, $A0909090);
  PaintBox1.Canvas.EndScene;
end;
```

Comment: DrawDashRect and DrawFocusRect are not the same thing. DrawDashRect is a simple DrawRect using a dashed pen. DrawFocusRect, which is a Windows API ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162479(v=vs.85).aspx ), uses a specific style and uses XOR so that drawing it a second time at the same place actually remove it.

Comment: Yeah well, and as an experienced programmer yourself, I left that exercise for you. ;o)

Comment: Of course I can emulate DrawFocusRect API but this would be bad programming if I simply missed the API. That's why I asked.

Comment: Well, to efficiently emulate DrawFocusRect, I need to be able to draw a line with XOR operation so that drawing the line again restore the pixels. Without XOR, I need to repaint a potentially large area which is slow since it is done each time the mouse move. I can not find how to select XOR mode for drawing (Equivalent of the VCL Canvas.Pen.Mode := pmXor).